# Can t see the output of my c++ program (debian)

Tags: c++

This might be a dumb question but...

I am programming some stuff in C++, it compile well on g++, but when I start the binary, there is nothing printed, even if I redirect the output in a file.

Example:
print.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/*...*/

int main ()
{
    //Table tab;
    //tab.set_all('_');
    //tab.setc(1, 1, 'c');
    //tab.setc(10, 5, 'd');
    cout << "print" << endl;
    //tab.print();
    cout << "end" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In shell:

```
>g++ print.cpp -o print
>print
>print > t
>cat t
>
```

Is it a problem in my code, or do I start my program in the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just call

```
> print
```

you are actually executing `/usr/bin/print`, that from the man page is

> NAME
>         run-mailcap, view, see, edit, compose, print - execute programs via entries in the mailcap file

Tu run your code you should do one of these three things:

1. If from the same directory

   ```
   > ./print
   ```
2. From an other directory

   ```
   > /path/to/exe/print
   ```
3. Add the directory where the exe live (`/path/to/exe/`) in the `PATH` before `/usr/bin`

   ```
   > export PATH=/path/to/exe:$PATH
   > print
   ```

   If you want to add it permanently, just add `export PATH=/path/to/exe:$PATH` to you `~/.profile` file

Answer (score 4):

By typing `print` in your shell you are executing the `print` command, which is a built-in of your shell that prints nothing without any arguments.

To launch your binary, type `./print`. This solves the confusion between the `print` command and the binary `print` in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

`print` is the name of a program from mailcap package. Typing `print` into the shell and hitting the Return key will execute it (from `/usr/bin/print`). Start your program by typing `./print`.